# Twig include template_from_string unexpected '&' when using default filter

Tags: php, twig, yii2-advanced-app, twig-extension, twig-filter

I am using the yiisoft/yii2-twig extension for Yii2 to render a template from a string.

String to be rendered:

```
{% set data = {
   "name": "john",
   "created_date": "22-05-2019"
} %}

{{ data.created_date }}

Hello {{data.name|default("john doe")}}
```

I am rendering this using the following view.twig:

```
<div>{{include(template_from_string(source))}}</div>
```

However, when I try to render this string twig returns the following error:

```
Unexpected character '&' in "__string_template__968dfade1318b592917e3a012d8c551b94f1c0c45f000ef60c8ea12df92abf4" at line 208.
```

String template:

```
{% set data = {
   "name": "john"
   "created_date": "22-05-2019"
} %}

{{ data.created_date }}

Hello {{data.name|default(&quot;john doe&quot;)}}
```

I know the error is at the default filter because I am using quotes. How can I solve this?

Comment: `<div>{{include(template_from_string(source|raw))}}</div>`?

Comment: Your code works without any problems for me? Can you show how you are initialising twig?

Comment: @Cyclonecode I am using the Yii2 advanced template framework so I initialize twig in the main config file and use the  StringLoaderExtension

Comment: @DarkBee same problem